# Array not working

Tags: php, arrays

I need help with `array()` because it's not working for some reason.

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET["page"]) && $_GET["page"] == array("i_gebruikers","gebruikerslijst","nieuwegebruiker","ban")) {
?>
    <a href="index.php?page=i_gebruikers"><li class="active">Gebruikers</li></a>
<?php } else { ?>
    <a href="index.php?page=i_gebruikers"><li>Gebruikers</li></a>
<?php } ?>
```

As you can see I'm trying to make a button which has the `active` class when you're on a page defined in the array. However it's completely ignoring the array.

Please help me out, it's very much appriciated!

Comment: You are essentially checking if the value of both counts of $_GET are equal to the full array of items, which they are likely not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are essentially checking if the value of both counts of $_GET are equal to the full array of items, which they are likely not.

```
if(isset($_GET['page']) && in_array($_GET['page'], array("i_gebruikers","gebruikerslijst","nieuwegebruiker","ban"))) {

}
```

Should work just fine.

Comment: Works great, thanks for sharing Marcus! Will accept your answer asap.

Comment: @J.Doe No problem! :) You can mark the answer as correct for future references. Cheers bud!